# Почему скрипты аналитики присылают пиксель в ответе?

Tags: http, яндекс-метрика

Фраза `поставить пиксель на сайт` означает установку скрипта аналитики - потому что в ответе от сервера аналитики приходит gif-изображение в 1px. Почему? Зачем нужно это изображение?

Comment: За тем что iframe или подзапрос xmlhttprequest и т п  - старые или мобильные браузеры не обрабатывают. А загрузку изображения - делают. Один - а зачем больше, это фейковая картинка. Ноль нельзя, один - можно. В чём суть - а куки, информация браузера и ip - они то передаются, с них и собирается метрика.

Comment: @nick_n_a, то есть, браузер делает запрос к картинке, передавая туда какие-то дополнительные данные, например, cookie. Запрос именно к картинке только ради кроссбраузерности. Правильно?

Comment: Запрос посредством картинки. Браузер делает зарос на url картинки что б получить её содержимое, запрос - отдаёт данные серверу где картинка - да. Кроссбраузерность - пожалуй да. 99.99% браузеров будут делать. Думаю с отключенными картинками, или в консольных браузерах сидит очень малый процент людей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iframe или подзапрос xmlhttprequest и т п - старые или мобильные браузеры не обрабатывают. А загрузку изображения - делают 99.99% браузеров (исключения есть но их очень мало). Один - а зачем больше, это фейковая картинка. Ноль нельзя, один - можно. В чём суть - а куки, информация браузера и ip - они то передаются, с них и собирается метрика.

Для того, что б браузер отобразил картинку, он делает GET-запрос на урл, записаный в src, и скачивает мааленькую картинку (удобно).

С запросом в поле Reffer передаётся страница, которая читает картинку. Браузер передает свой User-Agent и Accept-Languagе и другие заголовки, по которым можно идентифицировать клиента. ip-адрес плюс другие данные частично могут идентифицировать клиента если отключены куки. Куки передаются и принимаются (если включены) что позволяет оставлять отметку что этот клиент смотрел этот сайт.